# How to upload a word file from Windows Explorer using Protractor testing?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am trying to upload a word file from Windows Explorer using Protractor.

After I click the "Upload" button, the file explorer window pops up to choose a file, after open - the file name will be auto populated in the text box field. I can't enter the name of the file directly because it's a non-editable field:

```
<div class="form-control uneditable-input">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file ng-hide" ng-show="file != null"/> 
  <span class="fileinput-filename ng-binding"/>
</div>
```

How can I upload my file?

Comment: Can you share the link?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. It's not clear to me what your problem actually is. Is your problem that the file name field is non-editable?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the relativePath as "../../directory/sample.doc":

```
var absolutePath = require('path').resolve(__dirname, relativePath);
element(by.css("i span")).sendKeys(absolutePath);
browser.waitForAngular();
```

This would help you.